# How to display taxonomy order child, parent

Tags: terms

I have taxonomy="local", Term:
ABC (parent)
 - HCM
   - Q1
   - Q2
   - Q3

I used code in single_post_type:
`<?php echo get_the_term_list(get_the_ID(), 'local', '', ', ', ''); ?>`
but it display by letter (ABC,HCM,Q1,Q2,Q3).
I want display child first->parent: Q1,Q2,Q3,HCM,ABC
Please help me !!!
thanks
[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aparna_29 , post Test Bình Dương ABC ( parent )
Thuận An HCM ( child 1 )
An Phú ( child 2 )
[image: Get tax]

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code in functions.php file of child theme or custom plugin

```
add_filter( "term_links-local", 'reverse_order' );
function reverse_order($links)
{
    $new = array_reverse($links);
    return $new;
}
```

Comment: Any post have child 2 is still showing last, HCM,ABC,Q1(child 2 )

Comment: Please help me Aparna_29 !!!

Comment: You have same category order as mentioned above,right? If yes then it should work. Let me know your terms order.